# Ссыдки вида sait.com/100500

Tags: mod_rewrite, php, ссылки

Добрый день! На сайте есть ссылки вида:

```
sait.com/profile.php?id=100500
```

Как переделать все ссылки на:

```
sait.com/100500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут дело не в PHP, а в файле конфигураций Apache.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Это лишь маскирует вид GET-запросов под тот, что вам нужен. С помощью PHP этот запрос надо обработать. Смотрите в сторону паттерна MVC.

Comment: Да при чём же тут MVC?  
Это Front Controller.

Comment: Я не говорю, что это каким-либо образом связано с данным паттерном. Я говорю, что следует использовать для большего удобства =)